# For all integers $x$ and $y$, if $ x^3 + x = y^3 + y$ then $x = y$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

For all integers $x$ and $y$, if $x^3 + x = y^3 + y$ then $x = y$.

This is what I have done so far:

Proof: Suppose $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary integers. We know that $x^3 + x = y^3 + y$, we want to prove that $x = y$.

So, this is logically making sense, so it is true. any hints please?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof:

$x^3+x = y^3+y$

$x^3-y^3+x-y = 0$

$(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2) + x-y = 0$

$(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2+1) = 0$

Either$ x-y = 0$ or $(x^2+xy+y^2+1) = 0$

The reason why $(x^2+xy+y^2+1)$ is $((x^2+(\frac{y}{2})^2) + \frac{3}{4}y^2 + 1)$ where for any integer x and y, you have the two squares which can be 0 or greater than 0 + 1. Hence the term cannot be equal to 0.  The other responder has made this point which was very obvious to me before.

But the latter is not equal to 0 for integers x and y

Hence $x-y = 0 \Longrightarrow x= y$

Comment: You can produce $\Rightarrow$ by typing \Rightarrow in math mode; you can produce $\Longrightarrow$ by typing \Longrightarrow in math mode.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, Shall use form now on. Learnt something new.  Thank you sir

Answer (score 6):

$$
x^3+x=y^3+y\Longrightarrow x^3 - y^3 + x - y = 0\Longrightarrow (x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2 + 1) =0
$$
But
$$
x^2 + xy + y^2 + 1 = \left(x+\frac y2\right)^2 + \frac34 y^2 + 1 > 0,
$$
and $x=y$ immediately.

Actually, that follows from that: $f(x)=x^3+x$ is strictly increasing (because $f'(x)=3x^2 + 1 > 0$ for all $x$). Taking derivative is much faster.

Comment: You don't even need to take derivatives. A sum of two strictly increasing functions is itself strictly increasing, and $x^3$ is hopefully known to be strictly increasing already.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes, but it was my first idea

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x) = x^3 + x$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$. As $x$ and $y$ increase, so too does $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.

Assume for contradiction there exists $y\neq x$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$. Then, WLOG, let $x > y$. We have $f(x) = f(y)$, but $f(x) = f(x)$, which means the function $f(\cdot)$ in $[y,x]$ has slope $0$. This is a contradiction to the fact that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^3-y^3+x-y=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2+1)=0$$
has no other solution than $x=y$, because solving the quadratic term for $y$ give a negative discrimiant $x^2-4(x^2+1)$.